# A rebellious spouse in Beis Din today

Tags: halacha, divorce

The [Rambam describes](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/4114.htm#17) how to handle a case where a couple is divorcing and one spouse claims the other is rebellious (refusing marital relations) and the other is insisting that this is not the case (financial penalties are assessed on the offender).

> מחרימין בתחילה, על מי שהוא מורד ולא יודה בבית דין; ואחר כך, אם לא הודו--אומרין להם, התייחדו בפני עדים.  נתייחדו ועדיין הם טוענין, מבקשין מן הנטען ועושין פשרה כפי כוח הדיין

(This is quoted verbatim in [Shulchan Aruch Even HaEzer 77:4](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x7721))

Basically, in the end the Beis Din has to make a compromise, after trying a couple of things to make the offender admit (or change). How is that compromise effectively handled today in Beis Din?

I guess simplest is to discuss the case of the wife being the accused party, since it the financial penalty is more straight forward - she just loses her Kesuba. For the husband, it would further entail problems of determining the penalty amount in today's currency.